# Gamelift Matchmaking times out after match found

Tags: amazon-gamelift

Hoping to get some insight into the behavior I am seeing while trying to use GameLift Matchmaking.

I have my configuration setup as such that it does **not** require player acceptance, as such:

```
    GameLiftMatchmakingConfiguration:
      Type: AWS::GameLift::MatchmakingConfiguration
      Properties: 
        AcceptanceRequired: false
        ...
```

When I go to the GameLift console and into the configuration I see that it was correctly set as well that it does **not** require acceptance.

This is where I am confused, because now I have it working where it places 2 users in `PotentialMatchCreated` and I get this event from GameLift. Then 30 seconds later, I get more events stating that these placements timed out and searching again.

The [configuration documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamelift/latest/apireference/API_MatchmakingConfiguration.html) states that `AcceptanceTimeoutSeconds` is only required if `AcceptanceRequired` is true, which it is not for me.

the [acceptance documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamelift/latest/apireference/API_AcceptMatch.html#gamelift-AcceptMatch-request-PlayerIds) states that you only call this `When FlexMatch builds a match, all the matchmaking tickets involved in the proposed match are placed into status REQUIRES_ACCEPTANCE`

Which its not, its in `PotentialMatchCreated`.

So my question is, what do I have to do to confirm a placement once GameLift places 2 users into a match? I am a bit surprised because I thought that the fact that it doesn't have to be accepted would mean that its automatically accepted match.

Also theres very little documentation I found regarding what to do in this situation, given the nature of this service not being as known as others I totally expected that but really hoping someone can help me on what to do next.

Any insight or help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE1:

Additional information: I do not need to utilize GameLift fleets or builds at all. We have a browser game we are building and just want to utilize the matchmaking feature. So we dont have any game servers or anything like that, its just on our website where they would play the game and use our api's/websockets that puts the matchmaking on the server and notify the client when a match has been found with all the subsequent details.

UPDATE2:

To confirm my suspicions I decided to actually try to use the [accept match](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamelift/latest/apireference/API_AcceptMatch.html#gamelift-AcceptMatch-request-PlayerIds) endpoint and see what happens. Just as the documentation states, you can only accept a match if it requires acceptance. I get an error stating that I cannot accept a match that is not in `REQUIRE_ACCEPTANCE` state. Guessing this is a bug on AWS's side, I don't see any other endpoints that I can hit for being in state `PotentialMatchCreated`.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue. It has to do with the `FlexModeMatch` on the `GameLiftMatchmakingConfiguration`. For my use case, just needing matchmaking, `STANDALONE` is the correct implementation because we aren't having GameLift actually create game servers/sessions for us. I had mine using `WITH_QUEUE` which is why I believe I was having issues. Seemingly working correctly now.